# Отключение авто-корректировки в LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, material-design

Есть `RecyclerView`, две кнопки (лайк и дизлайк), посередине количество лайков.

Справа от него имеются некоторые слова, когда количество лайков отрицательное или добавляется еще один разряд(десятки, сотни, тысячи), то слово смещается в сторону автоматически.

Я не нашел ни одного примера, каким образом это можно было бы обойти либо отключить.

Сразу уточню, что там есть костыли в виде `TextView`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/thumpup"
        android:layout_width="27dp"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/thumbupgrey" />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/likes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="likes" />



    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/thumpdown"
        android:layout_width="27dp"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:src="@drawable/thumbdowngrey" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/mainwords2"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/mainwords"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        аndroid:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/info"
        android:id="@+id/infobtn" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

За счет того что в первом `TextView` Вы выставили `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`, а во втором `match_parent`, первый бедт двигать второй. С минимум правок можете так попробовать, веса подправьте под свои нужды:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/thumpup"
            android:layout_width="27dp"
            android:layout_height="27dp"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/likes"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="likes" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/thumpdown"
            android:layout_width="27dp"
            android:layout_height="27dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:id="@+id/mainwords2"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:id="@+id/mainwords"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            аndroid:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:id="@+id/infobtn" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Спасибо, я по невнимательности своей не подумал про матч парент